# Bad CPU Type when running mono script

Tags: macos, mono

I'm trying to get mono to work on my iMac. I'm running the latest version (3.2.4) and OSX 10.9. Whenever I use the "mono" command in Terminal.app, I get this error:

> -bash: /usr/bin/mono: Bad CPU type in executable

What's the issue here?

**Edit:**

More information:

```
$ file:
/usr/bin/mono: Mach-O executable ppc
$ arch
i386
$ machine
i486
$ uname -a
Darwin Ethan-Baileys-iMac-2.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: How did you originally install mono?

Comment: I used the package downloaded from the website, the MRE found here: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was because mono was trying to run 32-bit (even though it's supposed to default to 64-bit from 5.2).

https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/macos/: 
"Starting from Mono 5.2 the mono command defaults to 64-bit, 
you can use the --arch=32/64 switch to control the bitness."

However, I also found this still didn't work so I just went to /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands and deleted mono32 all together, everything runs fine now. I cannot, however, say with certainty that this is a good or safe thing to do. But it did fix my problem.

Comment: for me it's "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.6.0/bin/mono32" that I deleted that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that build of mono does not support any of the same architectures as your version of OS X does on your computer.

<del>What are the outputs of the commands `file /usr/bin/mono`, `arch`, `machine`, and `uname -a`?</del>

With this information, I can tell you that you are trying to run a PowerPC-only build of mono on a version of OS X which no longer includes Rosetta, and thus is incapable of running it.

Comment: file: /usr/bin/mono: Mach-O executable ppc
arch: i386 machine: i486 uname -a: Darwin Ethan-Baileys-iMac-2.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Okay, is there a version that's right for my computer? This was the one I found on the site.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I re-installed mono and it worked. I bet I had really really old version of it.

https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

Answer (score 0):

i solved this question by open epicgameslauncher app, which lets me install rosetta.